# How we can call a function after location reload in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Below are 2 jquery function. When I call the getData() function I want to reload the page then call the play_audio() function. But it is not working. Could anyone help me on this?

```
 function getData(id){
       if(id){
           location.reload();
           play_audio(id);
       }
    }


function play_audio(id) {
$('.load-container').show();        
var action_url = HTTP_ROOT + "/site/getaudiofile/";
$.ajax({
    url: action_url,
    data: {"audio_id": id},
    method: "post",
    async: false,
    success: function (res) {
        AP.destroy();
        res = JSON.parse(res);
        var resdata = new Array();
        resdata = res.data;
        var action = 'add';
        var index = 0;
        var title = resdata[index].title;
        muviAudioMusicPlayerObj = [];
        updateQueueList(resdata,action,index);
        $('.art-desc h6').html(title);
        $('.load-container').hide();
    }
});
```

}

Comment: When you reload the page, you reload the page - your current execution context is gone. Can you call `play_audio` in response to a user action without reloading ? Alternatively, you can you can inject a url parameter into the html page server-side in a suitable place (maybe a `data-` attribute, or opt for @Jeppsen's idea) and have an an `onload` handler start the audio contingent of that value, or you  alter the onload handler itself.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a hash to your url before reloading and then look for the hash:

```
function getData(id){
     if (id) {
         location.hash = 'playaudio-' + id;
         location.reload();
     }
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (location.hash.indexOf('#playaudio') !== -1) {
        var splitHash = location.hash.split('-');
        var id = splitHash[1];
        play_audio(id); 
    }
});
```

Comment: As per your answer the page reloads with a hash tag like #playaudio. But in document ready how can I get the id, that is need for play_audio() function?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution to the missing id problem @PrakashKumarGuru

Comment: Thank you so much @Jeppsen for your answer. It is working fine

Comment: Great and simple solution